# Creating partition (Data Tiering) on the basis of collection

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I want to partition data (Data Tiering) on the basis of `collection` in which the document is. Is there any example to do it on the basis of collections. I tried using `collection lexicon` option but it is behaving in an unpredictable manner. It would be great if I can get an example of how to configure data tiering on the basis of some collections. If an example is not possible some pointers also might work.

Answer (score 1):

Partitioning data requires two steps: database and forest configuration.

It sounds like you've done the first step: set the assignment policy to range, then select the collection lexicon.

The second step is at the forest level, where you [create a partition](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/tiered-storage#id_48262) by providing the range of values for the partition keys.

For the case of using collections, a complicating factor is what happens if a document is in more than one collection. I'm not sure what happens in that case.

Comment: Thanks @Dave. I am dealing with collections, I am specifying name of collection in _lower bound_. Is this fine? How can I specify multiple collections? 

Moreover, It is not working on expected lines even in case of one collection. For single collection it is inserting all the documents with *any collection* specified into the collection partition, while it is inserts all the document without any collection into the default partition.